# Creating QuickSight dataset based on DynamoDB table data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-quicksight

I need to create an analysis in QuickSight based on a specific DynamoDB table named "DeploymentHistory." What's the best way to create a dataset in QuickSight from DynamoDB data? The data needs to be the most recent every time the analysis is opened. In QuickSight's dataset creation mode, there's no option for DynamoDB as a data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do so is using the Athena DynamoDB Connector:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-dynamodb.html

Guide:

https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/visualising-your-amazon-dynamodb-data-with-amazon-quicksight-14n4